# How to get email from Active Directory when connected using server.xml from Tomcat 6

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, active-directory, ldap

Right now I have a login form that uses j_security_check to check for users in the active directory. But I need the logged in user's email which I have no clue on how to access or get. I found a tutorial that lets me get their login name and roles in AD but not sure how I would get the user's email.

```
    Hello, <%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %>
<%
final Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal(); 
GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = (GenericPrincipal) userPrincipal; 
final String[] roles = genericPrincipal.getRoles();
out.println("<p>You have " + roles.length + " role(s).</p>");
out.println("<ul>");
for(String role : roles) {
        out.println("<li>" + role);
}
out.println("</ul>");
%>
```

Comment: If @EJB's answer is correct and solves your problem, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to organize your own JNDIRealm variant that places the email address somewhere you can find it, e.g, the request attributes, the Subject if you're using that.